# Writing Cucumber Scenario for testing REST APIs

Tags: rest, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to Cucumber Testing framework and I am supposed to use cucumber for testing REST API.

For our understanding, lets say there is a REST API with endpoint http://localhost:8080/REST/coffee/search
and accepts three query params "type", "toppings" and "cost". There are several combinations of this query params are possible.

My Problem is in writing scenarios to test this API. I would like to call API by using several combination of these query parameters. 
But I am confused between using Data Tables or Scenario Outlines.

```
With Data Tables: //data is sent inside StepDefinition method as Data Table 

    Scenario: User Searches for Coffee
        Given Coffee exists with valid data 
        |type         |toppings      |  cost                |
        |Latte        |              |       1              |
        |Espresso     |Whipped Cream |       2              |       
        |Espresso     |              |       3.5            |
        When User call the API with given data
        Then Verify API Response for status

With Scenario Outline: // data is sent to individual params of stepdefinition.  

    Scenario Outline: User Searches for Coffee
        Given Coffee exists with valid data <type>, <toppings>, <cost>
        When User call the API with given data
        Then Verify API Response for status

    Examples:   

        |type         |toppings      |  cost                |
        |Latte        |              |       1              |
        |Espresso     |Whipped Cream |       2              |       
        |Espresso     |              |       3.5            |
```

is it Possible to get data tables in scenario outlines too if I try something like below?

```
Scenario Outline: User Searches for Coffee
        Given Coffee exists with valid data 
        When User call the API with given data
        Then Verify API Response for status

    Examples:   

        |type         |toppings      |  cost                |
        |Latte        |              |       1              |
        |Espresso     |Whipped Cream |       2              |       
        |Espresso     |              |       3.5            |



Since I have 10+ query params to use, Please suggest some best practices too.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better of writing a unit test to do this sort of testing. Then you can store your query params in a data structure and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not fully clear from your question, but maybe what you are looking for is that you can use example data also inside data tables of steps:

```
Scenario Outline: User Searches for Coffee
   Given Coffee exists with:
     | type   | toppings  | cost   |
     | <type> | <topping> | <cost> |
    When User call the API with given data
    Then Verify API Response for status
Examples:   
  | type         | topping       | cost |
  | Latte        |               | 1    |
  | Espresso     | Whipped Cream | 2    |       
  | Espresso     |               | 3.5  |
```